# Text (label) is not taking all available space in ionic list

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, android-listview, ionic4

I am newbie to Ionic and mobile development. I am using ionic list, how to make text full available screen (see Last received in picture) and is it okay to use `<ion-label>` around `<h4>` and `<p>`?

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor ="let connection of connections">
  <ion-avatar slot="start">
    <img [src]="connection?.picture">
  </ion-avatar>
<ion-label text-wrap>
  <h4>{{ connection?.name}}</h4>
  <p text-wrap> Last received:  {{ connection?.locationDesc }}</p>
</ion-label>

<ion-label slot="end" text-right>
  <p item-end> 2 Messages </p>
  <ion-button clear slot="end">View</ion-button>
</ion-label>          
</ion-item>
```

[image]

Comment: Please share your code..

Comment: code is already in the question

Comment: css code please

Comment: Oh, no css code yet, looking for CSS code. but using some Ionic css classes like "text-wrap"

Comment: can you share you code in stackblitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's just taking a little bit but what its actually doing is sharing 50 50 with the two labels you have put in to use as columns. It looks like its taking less than half because of the word-wrapping.

This is because labels are styled as flex items with those rules.

I managed to get it to this:

[image]

By using this code:

```
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar slot="start">
        <img src="/assets/matthew.jpg">
      </ion-avatar>
      <ion-label  class="ion-text-wrap">
        <h4>Some name</h4>
        <p> Last received: All plugins have two components - the native code (Cordova) and the
          JavaScript code. Cordova plugins are also wrapped in a Promise or Observable in order to provide a common
          plugin interface. Below are various framework options using the Camera plugin as an example. </p>
      </ion-label>
      <ion-note class="ion-text-end">
        <p> 2 Messages </p>
        <ion-button clear>View</ion-button>
      </ion-note>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

Basically I swapped the last `ion-label` to be an `ion-note` instead.

I have also messed around with other things like removing slots that weren't required and converting the attributes to [appropriate utility classes](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities) which is now considered a best-practice (since they introduced react and vue which don't support these attributes).